# Why is Rails adding an ORDER BY on my ActiveRecord queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord, tiny-tds

I'm using `tiny_tds` and `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` gems with my application. And every time I call a query it adds `ORDER BY [object].[id]` to the end.

**Example**
`School.limit(15)`

`EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [schools].* FROM [schools] WHERE [schools].[is_all_star_team] = 0  ORDER BY [schools].[id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY'`

When testing my queries through SSMS it seems with and without the order by is a pretty significant different in completion time.  I'm not sure how to remove it though when it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have a default scope set on the School model? If so this could be the culprit since it would be applied to all ActiveRecord calls, even simple ones like limit.

Comment: I do, is there a way to have a default scope without adding the order by?

Comment: Does your default scope have an order method call in it? If so you you can do something like: School.unscoped.limit(15) to ignore the scope for the call. [Here's a link to the docs on unscoped](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class)